# Are RecordTypes Indexed on Custom Objects?

Tags: largedatavolumes

Is RecordtypeId indexed on custom objects? According to two places in the documentation it says just standard objects, but that seems like a mistake.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/194/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: I agree that the documentation is a bit lacking that regard. You could run this query though to see if the recordId is indexed or not for a particular custom object: 

SELECT QualifiedApiName
FROM FieldDefinition
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName ='Vehicle__c' and IsIndexed = true

Comment: Oh damn, i didn't even think of that. thanks so much for the idea!